# Machine learning with caret: How to specify a timeout?

Tags: r, timeout, r-caret

Is it possible to specify a timeout when training a model in R using `train`from the `caret` library?
If not, does a R construct exist that wraps the code and can be terminated after a certain amount of time?

Comment: It's "timeOut" function ... https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.5.0/topics/withTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caret options are configured with the [`trainControl()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-79/topics/trainControl) object. It does not have a parameter to specify a timeout period.

The two settings in `trainControl()` that make the most impact on runtime performance are `method=` and `number=`. The default method in caret is `boot`, or bootstrapping. The default `number` for the bootstrapping method is 25 unless `method="cv"`.

Therefore, a `randomForest` run with caret will conduct 25 iterations of bootstrap samples, a very slow process, especially if run on a single processor thread.

### Forcing a timeout

R functions can be given a timeout period via the [`withTimeout()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.5.0/topics/withTimeout) function from the `R.utils` package.

For example, we'll run a random forest via caret with the mtcars data set, and execute 500 iterations of bootstrap sampling to get `train()` to run longer than 15 seconds. We will use `withTimeout()` to stop processing after 15 seconds of CPU time.

```
data(mtcars)
library(randomForest)
library(R.utils)
library(caret)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "boot",
                           number = 500,
                           allowParallel = FALSE)

withTimeout(
     theModel <- train(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars,method="rf",trControl=fitControl)
     ,timeout=15)
```

...and the first part of the output:

```
> withTimeout(
+      theModel <- train(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars,method="rf",trControl=fitControl)
+      ,timeout=15)
[2018-05-19 07:32:37] TimeoutException: task 2 failed - "reached elapsed time limit" [cpu=15s, elapsed=15s]
```

### Improving `caret` performance

Aside from simply timing out the `caret::train()` function, we can use two techniques to improve the performance of `caret::train()`, parallel processing and adjustments to the `trainControl()` parameters.

1. Coding an R script to use parallel processing requires the `parallel` and `doParallel()` packages, and is a multi-step process.
2. Changing `method="boot"` to `method="cv"` (k-fold cross validation) and reducing `number=` to `3` or `5` will significantly improve the runtime performance of `caret::train()`.

Summarizing techniques I previously described in [Improving Performance of Random Forest with caret::train()](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/pml-randomForestPerformance.md), the following code uses the `Sonar` data set to implement parallel processing with `caret` and `randomForest`.

```
#
# Sonar example from caret documentation
#

library(mlbench)
library(randomForest) # needed for varImpPlot
data(Sonar)
#
# review distribution of Class column
# 
table(Sonar$Class)
library(caret)
set.seed(95014)

# create training & testing data sets

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list=FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

#
# Step 1: configure parallel processing
# 

library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # convention to leave 1 core for OS 
registerDoParallel(cluster)

#
# Step 2: configure trainControl() object for k-fold cross validation with
#         5 folds
#

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 5,
                           allowParallel = TRUE)

#
# Step 3: develop training model
#

system.time(fit <- train(Class ~ ., method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl))

#
# Step 4: de-register cluster
#
stopCluster(cluster)
registerDoSEQ()
#
# Step 5: evaluate model fit 
#
fit
fit$resample
confusionMatrix.train(fit)
#average OOB error from final model
mean(fit$finalModel$err.rate[,"OOB"])

plot(fit,main="Accuracy by Predictor Count")
varImpPlot(fit$finalModel,
           main="Variable Importance Plot: Random Forest")
sessionInfo()
```